# How to calculate accuracy using keras method?

Tags: keras

I used exact same code as mentioned on this page and it works as expected.

https://medium.com/@vijayabhaskar96/tutorial-on-keras-flow-from-dataframe-1fd4493d237c

But I am not sure if the model has learned enough. How do I find accuracy of this model?

---

Update:

I can see Metric values are recorded at the end of each epoch.

I will like to know if acc: 5750 and val_acc: 0.5963 is acceptable for multi-class classification problem.

Comment: Based on my experience if val_acc  is higher than train_acc there is still some area to improve the model. It is hard to tell acc 59 is good or bad. it depends on many factors.

Comment: How do I plot the val_acc and train_acc side by side? (without any explicit programming :) )

Comment: Tensorboard is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable or not depends fully on your needs. A model with 59% accuracy may be considered useful in some cases.

However in general 0.59 accuracy means that 41% of the data is not classified correctly, which in most cases is not a very good score. You could try to train for more epochs.